# Smart Contract can not add transfer function inside the contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

How to add transfer function on a contract to a user using openZeppelin?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TokenSample is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("TokenSample", "SMPL") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 21000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

When I deploy the above contract, I get a transfer form with 2 parameter (recipient, amount). It's okay.

But because of one reason, I need to implement my own transfer function inside the contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TokenSample is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("TokenSample", "SMPL") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 21000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

 function getToken(uint256 _amount) external returns(bool)  {
   // my internal logic here
   transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    return true;
 }
}
```

From the code I got error : ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

I am not really sure but I guest it's because the token is belong to the owner not belong to the contract. What is the right way to implement that getToken method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transfer amount exceeds balance` error message comes from a failed check if the sender has enough balance. Source: [ERC20.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.3.3/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L231) on OpenZeppelin GitHub.

In case of the `transfer()` function being called from within a contract function (and not directly by the user), the sender is the contract.

So this line in your contract

```
transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
```

is trying to send `_amount` of tokens **from the contract address** to the user (executing the `getToken()` function). And when it's trying to transfer more tokens than the sender (the contract) owns, it fails with this error message.

---

This way you can mint new tokens (increasing the total supply) to the user.

```
function getToken(uint256 _amount) external {
    // TODO your own logic here
    _mint(msg.sender, _amount);
}
```

---

And if you want to mint some of the tokens to the contract address during deployment, you can use the `address(this)` as the receiver, which stands for the current contract address.

```
constructor() {
    // mint 10M tokens to the contract
    _mint(address(this), 10000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    
    // mint 21M tokens to the owner
    _mint(msg.sender, 21000000 * 10 ** decimals());

    // total supply is now 31M, where the contract owns 10M and the owner owns 21M
}
```

Comment: So how to make the sender get token by calling getToken method? Txs

Comment: @Yusnee If you want the user to receive the tokens from the contract balance (not changing the total supply), you need to send (or mint) some of the balance to the contract first... If you want them to get newly minted tokens (increasing the total supply), you can use the internal `_mint()` function. I updated my answer with an example of the latter.

Comment: Yes I have try _min but it increases the total supply.  I want to keep the total supply. My more question is : Why using openZeppelin make the token belong to owner but not the contract? Btw, In the above case, do I have to make the owner send all token to the contract?

Comment: @Yusnee I see your point now. You can mint tokens to the contract during deployment as well. I updated the answer with an example as well.

Comment: Okay. But it's not about the total supply but how the sender get the Token. What I am thinking from your opinion, I can use _mint, but limit the total minting to become the last max supply.